# Why and what are the differences between these two text files?

Tags: asmx, text-files

[image]

We were like migrating and old application to a new architecture. The two files shown in notepad are DAT files. The first file was created by the old application. The second one was created by the "new implementation".

A little history behind the new implementation: These applications (in the "new implementation") are supposed to be hosted in a web farm environment. There was a specific application called the **payroll** - this is the application responsible for the creation to the files shown below. I had used visual studio's pre-processed text templates to generate the DAT files. At the time there was no web service involved. But later we decided that the creation of such files needs to be centralized.

So we exposed a web service to do this.

Essentially there was no change in logic. I still used the pre-processed templates. But the output of this template was transmitted over the web to the web service. After which the files started appearing like as shown in the 2nd image.

There was no problem before the centralization. So what has happened here? How can I make the DAT file (in the new implementation) look the same as in the old?

Comment: Have you tried viewing these files in a hex editor?

Comment: It seems as the charset is different between the sender and recipient, rendering the linebreaks into little boxes. Also, Edward changed his name to Christopher.

Comment: Haha, that's because Christopher is his superhero name :D

Comment: I advice you to use Notepad++ and use the "View non printable characters" to see what characters you can't see in the two versions.

Comment: @ninetwozero: both files should look same. In the sample above, what you are seeting is the DAT files generated for two different employees.

Comment: You know, if you either gave more information or accepted one of the answers, or eventually gave the answer if different, it might help others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a a carriage return issue. I guess the web service use a UNIX server with Unix style line feeds, and the other file comes from a windows?
In that case, you'll just have to change endlines into CRLF.

Unix systems use  LF (0x0A), when Windows system require CR (0x0D) followed with LF (0x0A), so simply replace LF with CRLF, if it is your issue.

Comment: I think this helps better: earlier I used to send the text as one long string. Then I changed that parameter to a byte array. I've to convert the string to an ascii encoded byte array. It at least preserves data which goes over the wire (especially the CR and LFs)

Answer (score 3):

One probably uses `CR LF` = `\r\n`

The other probably just uses `LF` = `\n`

`CR` short for Carriage Return.

`LF` short for Line Feed.